# ResourceManager.GetString encoding

Tags: c#, .net

Which encoding is used by ResourceManager class [GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.getstring.aspx) method?

Comment: String objects in .NET, including the return value of GetString() are always encoded in utf-16.  This doesn't necessarily say anything about the encoding you used when you added the resource.

Comment: @Hans Passant - I probably misunderstand, but I think this is not what OP is asking. The question would be 'How String class stored internally in .NET?' if they wanted to know that, and the question would not be related to reading resource data.

Comment: @alex: Well, that's possible, I guess.  Isn't that the typical problem with cr*ppy one-liner questions?

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely uses [UTF-8 encoding.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) In many cases it would be a waste of space if it didn't.

How to prove:

Add 3 strings to the resources: filled with `A`, `¢` and .

[image]

Compile and open the binary:

[image]

It is clear that UTF-8 was used, as the first char was encoded as one byte, the second as two bytes and the third as 4 bytes.

Comment: That's not what GetString() returns.  You only demonstrated that the Chinese don't think much of utf8 being an efficient encoding.  But yes, a .resx file is an XML file encoded in utf8.

Comment: @Hans Passant - not sure I understood you. `GetString()` returns `String` object. This object will be represented in memory in the same encoding as any other string is (AFAIK UTF-16, but not sure). If I read the question correctly it is asking about what encoding will be used when string is read from binary. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: You're right, let's interpret this shoddy question in an interesting and educational way.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

That depends.

If it's an embedded resource no encoding is used, as the string is stored in unicode.

If it's a file based resource, that is, a resource that is read from an XML file, the encoding is that of the XML file.

Comment: I am asking about file based resource. But what if my file is not XML (it is just a text file)? Looks like Encoding.Default is used...

Comment: That also depends. If the file is added as an embedded resource, that is, you add as a `FILE` in the resource editor of visual studio, it is stored as string and the file is read as is by the compiler.

Comment: It doesn't depend. `ResourceManager.GetString` method uses UTF-8 always.